# jsoup unexpectedly fetching shopwiki image

Tags: java, jsoup, virus, malware

I am using the following code to fetch images from the web:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class fetchImageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        saveImage(args[0], args[1]);
    }

    private static boolean saveImage(String string, String destination) throws IOException {

        string = string.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        try {
            byte[] image = Jsoup.connect(string).ignoreContentType(true).timeout(10000).execute().bodyAsBytes();

            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);

            os.write(image);        
            os.close();

            return true;
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("couldn't open " + string);
            return false;
        }   

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("couldn't open - general exception" + string);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Due to a bug in some of my other code, I tried to fetch an image from a broken URL, of the form:

```
http://shop.foo.comhttp://shop.foo.com/1.jpg
```

My code ended up fetching a shopwiki image, like [image: shopwiki-image]

I am using jsoup-1.7.1.jar. Is there a virus on my server? Is there a virus with my jsoup jar file?

I really have no idea ...

Answer (score 1):

Several sites set up a system to protect the recovery of their image.

I guess you try to retrieve images shopwiki.com
I watched their URL to retrieve a picture is it is well established that security.

http://si4.shopwiki.com/i/data/120x120/18/4/2/aHR0cDovL2VjeC5pbWFnZXMtYW1hem9uLmNvbS9pbWFnZXMvSS81MVMwWTBuZHBjTC5qcGc=.jpg